# Asp.net Dropdown list's FindByValue issue related to page formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three dropdown lists:

```
//three dropdown lists as follow:
ddlStartupPage.Items.FindByValue(Session["StartUpPage"].ToString()).Selected = true;
ddlValue1.Items.FindByValue(Session["v1"].ToString()).Selected = true;
ddlValue2.Items.FindByValue(Session["v2"].ToString()).Selected = true;
```

I am using findByValue method of dropdownlists. The first line is running ok. But when I uncomment the last two lines, it's causing page formatting issues.

I am using master page and update panel in my asp.net page.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what issues this is causing other that they are "page formatting issues"

Comment: How can the `Selected` property of a `DropDownList` cause a _formatting_ issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
ddlproj.SelectedIndex = ddlproj.Items.IndexOf(ddlproj.Items.FindByText(dtproj.
Rows[0]["project"].ToString()));
```

Comment: ddlproj is dropdownlist and dtproj is datatable